# Doubts on OSGI usage

Tags: jboss, websphere, osgi, weblogic, blueprint-osgi

i have some requirements on my project that modularity appears to be needed, so i'm researching some approaches on the best way to do it.

Based on this, i found OSGI and sounds like a great deal, after some search and some tutorials i have some doubts.

In a high level i'm thinking in separate my modules by business segments, for instance, financial, invoices, registers, and so on.

1) I believe i can create bundles to separate these modules, i also saw that i can use osgi container to deploy those bundles. Is is possible to distribute this application on jboss, websphere and weblogic?

2) Is there any known disadvantage to make my application full dependent to OSGI? I mean, i only wanted to use OSGI to separate my modules and make deploy and version distribution easier?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As relates to WebSphere Application Server, the answer to your question #1 is positive. WAS has extended support for applications based on OSGi and has the notion of Web Application Bundle (WAB) and EJB bundle. You should take a look at the official documentation - [OSGi applications](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.osgi.nd.doc/ae/ca_about.html?lang=en).

You might also want to take a closer look at [Apache Aries](http://aries.apache.org/), the project that enables the use of OSGi for building applications in Java EE environment.